# WSO2 Micro Gateway - How to identify mutual SSL or Oauth2 request is comming to the gateway

Tags: api, wso2, api-gateway

I have a requirement to enable Oauth2 or Mutual SSL as authentication protocols.

If the incoming request is coming with mutual SSL then I need to check whether another header is present (X-sample-header) in the request. If it is not present throw a bad request error. Else pass-through

If the Oauth2 token is present and also the X-sample-header present then throw a bad request. Else pass-through

I'm using wso2 micro gateway 3.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are writing an interceptor as mentioned in https://mg.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/how-tos/message-transformation/write-java-interceptors/#writing-an-interceptor-in-java

You can check the headers in each request and execute this logic. In OAuth2 it should get Authorization header and MTLS, you won't get any header.